# How to populate a data for a field in mongoose, where reference is a nested array in model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I populate **category** in courses model?
I have courses, courses will have category from categories->subcategories model.
I don't know how to populate from nested objects.
Reference model is category, I have to populate from array **subcategories**!

```
**courses:**
const CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            userId: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'users'
            },
            name: {
                type: String
            },
            description: {
                type: String
            },
            category: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'category'
            }
        });

**category:**
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    subcategories: [{
        name: {
            type: String
        }
    }]

});
const Category = mongoose.model('category', CategorySchema);
module.exports = Category;
```

Answer (score 0):

use seprate collection for subCetagory like:

```
**courses**
const CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        userId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
        },
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        description: {
            type: String
        },
        category: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'SubCategory'
        }
    });
 **SubCategory:**
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");

 const SubCategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
 },
 categorie: {
     type: String,
     ref: "category"
 }

});
const SubCategory = mongoose.model('category', SubCategorySchema);
module.exports = SubCategory;
**Category**
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
},
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
subcategories: [
    {
        type: Schema.types.objectId,
        ref: "SubCategory"
    }
]

});
```

then just add subcetagory id to course when insert new course or update a course and when you want to get course along with subcetagory and category use [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) query of mongoose